# DataGrid Change Background of a single cell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, background, converters

I am trying to set the background color of a single cell in my ´DataGrid´, but everytime I set the color to a DataGridCell, the background of the entire row is overwritten.
My code:

```
 <Setter Property="CellStyle">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding id, Converter={StaticResource TheConverter}}" />
                        </Style>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>


public class CellHighlighterConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value.ToString() == "1") return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

So the problem is... the entire row with the ID "1" is red! Not just the id cell. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following workaround:

1. Wrap the cell content with a Grid.
2. Set the Grid to stretch both horizontally and vertically.
3. Now change the background color of the grid, instead the background color of the cell.

I haven't tested it myself, but I think its worth a shot.